# Is there any easy technique to identified guitar/chord tab of any song?

Tags: guitar

Im  a poor  Guy, I can not afford coaching for  Guitar classes.

I have seen  many videos in you tube  .  Most  are  them providing  Guitar chord and Tab .

My  question is that  how can we  know the  guitar chord/tab    about any  song ?

Is there  any easy technique  to  identified  guitar/chord tab  of  any song ?

Comment: Can I assume that you know the chord progression and perhaps melody of the song and all you want is tabs,  or is it possible that you want to know the tabs even though you don't know the chord progression (e.g. you want tabs for a piece with no published transcriptions or sheet music, you want tabs for "We Wish You a Merry Christmas")?

Comment: @Dekkadeci ya   i can play  tab of  any song .....but   my tab is not in exact scale    and i don't  know  that    what  is   the  exact scale.. of any song ?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I mean this: are you trying to figure out tabs (fret numbers on strings) given existing sheet music, or are you unable to rely on existing sheet music in order to create your tabs?

Comment: Sir im unable to rely  and one  thing that  i don't know  how  to read  the  Notation also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long process. 60 yrs after starting to do just that, I'm still learning. Firstly, don't rely too much on merely playing what you're told on the 'net. Learn which chords often go with which others. Learn lots of different chords - maj., min., all the 7ths, to start with. Learn some scales, and listen to the differences in sound between them. Then take some simple tunes, and find the key, which will provide good clues as to the scale and chords used. Transcribe them onto guitar by ear, trial and error initially. It's a long process but listening carefully is always no. 1.

Comment: sir  can u provide me  links/sources   where i can get  all  the chord scale ?

Comment: No. Mainly because I don't use them as resources. However, there are many many sources that explain these things. Just Google.

Answer (score 1):

I agree largely with Tim. But I would try to play each day at least 10 songs - traditional, folk, children etc. - with help of the web (searching in youtube, chord, and tab or just lyrics with chords). You will find that most of them have the same patterns and progressions and you will also learn to identify errors. But mind that there are always different solutions!